# How to refine CSS media types and properties?

Tags: html, css

Right now I have this code in my HTML document:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media handheld
    {
        footer{
            padding: 5% 0;
        }
        footer h6{
            font-size:.4em;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 900px)
    {
        footer{
            padding: 5% 0;
        }
        footer h6{
            font-size:.4em;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 320px)
    {
        footer{
            padding: 5% 0;
        }
        footer h6{
            font-size:.4em;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)
    {
        footer{
            padding: 5% 0;
        }
        footer h6{
            font-size:.4em;
        }
    }
</style>
```

As you can probably see from this code, I want to apply the same two properties to the same two elements for each of these media conditions. I was wondering if there was a better way to do this—without linking to an external CSS document. Thanks!

Comment: I'll give an "off topic" answer - you should look at SASS if you find yourself repeating CSS properties: http://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/). Commas act like OR operators.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px), (max-device-width: 900px)
```

Comment: Thank you! One more question, though. If I wanted this to apply to handheld styles regardless of the window size or pixel ratio, would this work: `@media handheld, screen and (max-device-width: 900px), (max-width: 320px), (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){` or would the window size and pixel ratio restrictions be applied to the handheld media type?

Comment: @Larry Yes, I believe so.